# Use PayPal Express Checkout in an online marketplace

Tags: paypal, express-checkout, marketplace

I'd looking at using PayPal's Express Checkout in an online marketplace. By this I mean, allowing users to send money to other users in exchange for digital goods. So far, the examples and source code I have found requires an email, password & API signature (the 2 latter ones, I don't want to store for obvious security reasons).

I'm just wondering if there is a way to use the Express Checkout in this situation, using something like an email to send the money from the buyer to the seller.

If it isn't possible to have direct payments between the two, would the following be feasible? From the Rest SDK there is a way to send payments (business -> user), so was wondering if I made it so: buyer -> my site -> seller.

Thanks in advance for any help! If you've got any code examples, documentation or whatever else (preferably for php as that's what I'm going to use), that would be great! Thanks again!

Comment: If you use the older SOAP Adaptive Payments API, you can just put in the sellers email address and payments will go directly to them. https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php

Comment: @blazerunner44, alright! Thank you :)

Comment: You can do the same with the regular Express Checkout, which I recommend over the Adaptive Payments platform simply because the checkout experience is better.  EC supports parallel payments, and when you do that you can just add the email address to each payment in the single request to specify where the money should go.  You can use the same method with a single receiver, though, and have payments go directly there without any permissions API setup or anything like that required.

Comment: @AndrewAngell, I was originally trying to use EC due to the better checkout experience for the user, just haven't been able to crack PayPal's tutorials! I've been testing with some more basic stuff in an attempt to understand it. Thanks for giving me the insight that EC can still do what I'm looking for! If you want, post as an answer and I'll set as solution :)

Comment: Are you working with PHP?  If so this [class library](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make the API calls very quick and easy for you.

Comment: @AndrewAngell, yeah I am. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

You can go with paypal adaptive solution, when customer making payment using paypal in your website, instantly seller will get an product amount in the paypal account and commission amount will be send to website admin paypal account. Please check and integrate paypal adaptive module in your website.